# Cannot see any option in WSO2 Identity Server dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 but I'm getting a strange issue using the dashboard.
I installed it on a server of mine (so it is not on localhost) and configured the following configuration files so that WSO2 knows where to point

File `wso2is-5.0.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
<HostName>SERVER_IP</HostName>
<MgtHostName>SERVER_IP</MgtHostName>
```

File `wso2is-5.0.0/repository/conf/security/saml2.federation.properties`

```
WSO2=https://SERVER_IP:9445/samlsso
```

File `wso2is-5.0.0/repository/conf/security/sso-idp-config.xml`

```
<SSOIdentityProviderConfig>
    <ServiceProviders>
        <ServiceProvider>
            <Issuer>wso2.my.dashboard</Issuer>
            <AssertionConsumerService>https://SERVER_IP:9443/dashboard/acs</AssertionConsumerService>
...
```

As stated in the [official documentation](http://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+the+Dashboard) I should see some blocks and after clicking the "View details" buttons I should be able to do the operations of the dashboard related to each block.

However, when I login in the Dashboard I can see the blocks, but when I click "View details" I get a blank-content page a you can see in the following screenshot of the "My Profiles" page

[image]

The same thing happens for the other blocks.

What can I do? Maybe I didn't configure something?

Thank you in advance

Giulio

Comment: Open your browser console and check for any 404 errors. Above dashboard renders gadgets.. seems they didn't configure on correct url

Comment: Hi @Dakshika, thanks for you response. 

When I open the page in the web browser I get these errors in the console http://pastebin.com/HYBG8qcE. Moreover when I click the "View details" button of the My Profiles box I get these errors: http://pastebin.com/bXUJqXrB. 

It seems the web application tries to load some content from localhost. 

Do you know where I should configure these hostnames (apart from the already configured ones)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have installed the identity server other than `localhost`,  You would see some issues with dashboard.  I also experienced same type of issues. But you can resolve them by configuring the host name and port properly. Unfortunately there are few places that you need to edit. Please find them below.  I have already to report a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2544)  to improve them to configure from one config file.

1. repository/conf/carbon.xml
2. repository/conf/security/sso-idp-config.xml
3. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/dashboard/apis/gadget.json
4. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/gadgets/account-recovery/gadget.xml
5. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/gadgets/identity_management/gadget.xml
6. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/gadget.xml
7. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/gadgets/user_auth_apps/gadget.xml
8. repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/gadgets/user_profile/gadget.xml
9. modify the url of the user_profile (i.e. http://{IP}:{port}/portal/gadgets/user_profile/gadget.xml ) in "repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/dashboard/apis/gadget.json" file in to HTTP and Port in to 9763.

Comment: That's the way to solve this issue! I just wonder why there isn't any documentation about that.

Thank you again

Comment: Related JIRA (indicates that this is being fixed in 5.1): https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2964

Comment: I believe I made the changes from 1 to 9 in my vm, however the login link on the dashboard still points to localhost, could it be that I missed something? PS context is running IS 5.0.0 using vagrant / ubuntu.

Comment: Worth taking note of the installation prerequisites (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Installation+Prerequisites), you need to run it on JDK  7, easy mistake to make on localhost. Just did this and some JSP pages are blank.