# WSO2 Dashboard Jaggery Gadgets Config HTTPS

Tags: https, wso2, identity, dashboard

I'm in the process of configuring the **WSO2 IS 5.0.0 Dashboard**. I've followed this previous post to configure the gadgets: [Cannot see any option in WSO2 Identity Server dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862167/cannot-see-any-option-in-wso2-identity-server-dashboard)
since they weren't showing up/displaying properly.

In the config files though everything is **HTTP**. I plan on using a proxy and having everything behind **HTTPS**. Therefore, I'd like everything in the config files to be **HTTPS**.

I tried changing everything in the the config files mentioned in the above link to **HTTPS** and included port **9443**, but when I go to the dashboard the gadgets are missing. I also tried leaving off the 9443 and just having https://ip-address/.... but it the gadgets and everything will not show up.

Are there additional files, other than the ones mentioned in the link, that need to be configured? Is it possible to have it set as https or can it only be http?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have mentioned in the previous post has been fixed in IS 5.1.0 and there are lot of improvements shipped with this version. Now you will be able to access all your gadgets via HTTPS without configuring in all the mentioned files. By default the dashboard and all the gadgets will be accessible through HTTPS protocol. But you can configure it by changing only in a single file now [1].

You can download the IS 5.1.0 from [2]

[1] {IS_HOME}/repository/conf/identity/sso-idp-config.xml

[2] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/