# Unable to login to Dashboard for WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have setup a WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 and I was able to login to carbon managment console with the user "admin". But when I try to login to dashboard, it failed.
Been troubleshooting and reading the documentation and stackoverflow for clue but couldn't find one and I am not sure which part of the configuration I did wrong.

Following are the things that I set for my WSO2IS:

1. I change the host name from localhost to my server ip in the following files:

   - repository/conf/carbon.xml
   - repository/conf/identity.xml
   - repository/conf/security/sso-idp-config.xml
   - repository/conf/security/saml2.federation.properties
   - repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml
   - repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
2. I also did the same steps indicated in this [Cannot see any option in WSO2 Identity Server dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862167/cannot-see-any-option-in-wso2-identity-server-dashboard)

Following are the server log produced from the server where I setup the WSO2IS

```
[2015-08-10 11:47:48,530]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : /opt/WSO2/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2015-08-10 11:47:49,038]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2015-08-10 11:47:49,774]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ui.internal.ApplicationMgtUIServiceComponent} -  Application Management UI bundle acticated!
[2015-08-10 11:47:49,944]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.admin.FileBasedConfigManager} -  A SSO Service Provider is registered for : wso2.my.dashboard
[2015-08-10 11:47:50,039]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.internal.IdPManagementServiceComponent} -  Identity Application Management Database initialization not attempted since 'setup' variable was not provided during startup
[2015-08-10 11:47:50,299]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent} -  Identity Database schema initialization check was skipped since 'setup' variable was not given during startup
[2015-08-10 11:47:51,868]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9443
[2015-08-10 11:47:51,868]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9763
[2015-08-10 11:47:53,001]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://172.18.64.178:11111/jndi/rmi://172.18.64.178:9999/jmxrmi
[2015-08-10 11:47:53,001]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Identity Server-5.0.0
[2015-08-10 11:47:53,002]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 109 sec
[2015-08-10 11:47:53,410]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://172.18.64.178:9443/carbon/
[2015-08-10 11:47:54,205]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} -  Started thrift entitlement service at port:10500
[2015-08-10 11:48:09,003]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.SchemaBuilder} -  XACML policy schema loaded successfully.
[2015-08-10 11:49:08,437]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'WSO2/admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-08-10 11:49:08,437+0800]
[2015-08-10 11:49:24,528]  INFO {JAGGERY.login:jag} -  connecting to https://172.18.64.178:9443/services
[2015-08-10 11:49:43,806]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2015-08-10 11:49:43,847] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator} -  Authentication Request is rejected. Authorization Failure.
[2015-08-10 11:49:43,848]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2015-08-10 11:49:43,848+0800]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason for this issue can be the user you try to login does not have log permission. Therefore Can you please check the user has login permission

You can view roles and users from the Identity Server management console.

Comment: not sure why, I went back uncheck and recheck it back again on the login persmission and it works like charm. Thank you.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. On a fresh default installation of IS 5.0.0, the "Everyone" role does not have "Login" permission. So no one except the admin user could login to the dashboard.