# wso2 identity server 5.1.0 dashboard items empty

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Have installed WSO2 IS on Ubuntu 14.04. All seems to be good, apart from when user logs in to dashboard, all the options are blank. I've searched google, but unfortunately no luck.

Dashboard screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such behavior in IS 5.1.0. when I log in to the dashboard using the link https://localhost:9443/carbon/ I could see everything. Please have a look in to the image.Please refresh and see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely identical to the post (WSO2 V 5.0) regrading missing setup of the host and domain name. It requires adjustment of a few  configuration files, as described at the following post:  [ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862167/cannot-see-any-option-in-wso2-identity-server-dashboard) ]

Comment: Yes, I had previously set up V5.0 and changed hostname settings. However on this version, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using WSO2 IS on an internal domain.

Check your browser console and see if you are getting certification errors when you visit the dashboard, if so self sign a certificate with the domain name you are using and add it to the WSO2 keystore.

If remember correctly the certificates that ship with WSO2 IS are set to localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I am getting certificate errors referencing 'localhost'. I didn't realise that this could break the dashboard console though! I am in the process of ordering a certificate, so hopefully this will resolve the issue.